# Powershell: How to get the location of a file, depending on its name?

Tags: string, powershell, location, substring, exchange-server

So my task is to write a PS script, that outputs the location of a database file. The location of the file is:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Mailbox\Mailbox database Name\Mailbox database Name.edb
```

I figured I can get the name of my Exchange database with

```
Get-MailboxDatabase | fl Name
```

which has the output:

```
Mailbox Database 0161713049
```

which is the name of the db but there is a bunch of invisible characters before and after the actual name.

So my question is, how could I get rid of these invisible characters? I want to concat a string to make it look like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Mailbox\Mailbox Database 0161713049\Mailbox Database 0161713049.edb
```

I would need this code to work on servers with completely different database names too, so simply removing the unwanted characters from the start with .Remove() may help, but since I don't know for sure the length of the name of the database, I can't remove the characters at the end.

Also I can't get rid of the feeling that there is a much simpler way to get the location of my .edb file.

Comment: You shouldn't use `format-*` commands (`fl` is an alias for `format-list`) if you are going to further process the output because they apply special formatting that change the output object. Instead, use `Get-MailboxDatabase | Select -Expand Name`.

Comment: I haven't worked with Exchange since 2013, but back then it was `Get-MailBoxDatabase -Status |Select -Expand EDBFilePath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell treats almost all outputs as an object with properties in hashtable format like `@{Name=MYEXCHDB}`. When you just want a property value as a string instead, you must expand it like @AdminOfThings suggests:

```
Get-MailboxDatabase | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

To concatenate the name into a string:

```
$myString = "C:\path\to\$(Get-MailboxDatabase | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)"
```

And as @mathias-r-jessen suggests, the path to the database is another property you can get directly:

```
Get-MailboxDatabase | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EdbFilePath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PathName
```

Comment: You need to add the `-Status` parameter for it to return `EDBFilePath`

Comment: That's what I get for not testing the whole thing, I'm using Exchange2019 and didn't have to add `-status`, but the `EDBFilePath` is also an object that needs to be expanded again. Updated answer

Comment: There are all really helpful ideas. Thank you very much!